# Compound Index in Firebird

Tags: indexing, firebird

How can I build a compound index in Firebird database with one field ascending and another one descending? Like account number ascending and date in descending order.

Comment: What kind of queries you would like to use this index for?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create such index in Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebird syntax of [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-index.html#fblangref40-ddl-idx-create) only allows you to specify a direction for the index as a whole. It is not possible to order individual columns in the index.

Comment: can a compound index use a `computed by` column ?

Comment: @Arioch'The No they can't. To quote from the documentation _"computed fields cannot be used in an index"_